# Could be done this static button with java code?

Tags: java, android, button

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/randomImage"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    />
```

Especially I'm asking about those two properties:

```
android:drawableTop="@drawable/randomImage"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
```

This is how the buttons look:

[image]

The buttons are done with static xml.

Finally I have to answer my question:

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
```

correspondents to:

```
setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

and

```
android:drawableTop="@drawable/randomImage"
```

correspondents to:

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom);
```

Comment: How could I set gravity with both `center_horizontal|bottom`. I saw that there is a method `Button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)` and `Button.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)`, but how to apply the both. Also how could be done `android:drawableTop="@drawable/randomImage"`

Comment: I should attach an image of how the button appears.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Button mButton_dial = null;
     mButton_dial = new Button(this);
    mButton_dial.setText("Dial!");

    mLinearLayout_no_button = new LinearLayout(this);

    mLinearLayout_no_button.addView(mButton_dial);
    mButton_dial.setGravity(20);

    mButton_dial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {

      }
    });
```

Comment: What about `android:drawableTop="@drawable/randomImage"`?

Comment: Actually you're not right! I changed your answer `setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.BOTTOM);`

Comment: I don't know, why you vote negative, after you gave me a wrong answer?!??